# Can ‘benefactor’ can be used to refer to someone given the responsibility of a property?

Tags: word-usage, confusables

I am reading a book called ‘Pure Dead Brilliant’ by Debi Gliori. I’m having trouble understanding a sentence. The male protagonist in the book, a kid named Titus inherits his grandfather’s wealth but his sister Pandora doesn’t share the fortune, this creates a funny conflict between the two. In this context, a particular line reads- ‘...three months past, when Titus discovered that he was the chosen benefactor of their grandfather’s vast hoard of money...’ I am confused because I know a ‘benefactor’ is someone who is the provider, and the receiver is the ‘beneficiary’. To quote wsu.edu:  “Benefactors give benefits; beneficiaries receive them. We expect to hear of generous benefactors and grateful beneficiaries.”
If that’s so then why the author has described Titus as the ‘benefactor’ here? My best guess is that it is a way to say that Titus is given the responsibility / freedom to spend his grandfathers money and that’s why now he is a potential *provider*. I might be totally wrong but I want to understand this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: To be honest, my first reaction is that the author actually meant "beneficiary".

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Would you please edit your question and provide your research for the definitions of *benefactor* and *beneficiary*? (By providing these, we won't have to cover the same ground.)

Comment: @user888379 Do you mean to say it’s a slip? Not possible because books go through multiple rounds of proof correction before going for print.

Comment: @rajah9 I always knew the difference between benefactor and beneficiary, but anyway I’ve edited the question and quoted a few lines on the subject from the Washington State University website.

Comment: It *is* definitely possible that it is simply an error. Multiple rounds of proofing don't guarantee that *all* mistakes will be caught. Haven't you ever noticed typos in other books?

Comment: @nnnnnn, I understand your point and maybe it’s possible on extremely rare cases. I don’t have much experience with English books- I’ve read maybe 100 at the most. Typos are almost non-existent in the books published in my native language (Bengali), especially if it is coming from a reputed publisher, that’s why this sounded so impossible to me. Also, if it is a mistake at all then it’s too prominent to be overlooked by the editors. I’d wait for a few more replies until fully convinced